# Using Wix to Deploy an Outlook Add-In

Tags: deployment, wix, vsto, outlook-addin

I have a requirement to create an installer for an Outlook 2003 add-in that was created with VSTO.

We currently are using Wix for our installers as they play nice with MSBuild and I need to use it to create the installer for the outlook add-in.

I have no experience with outlook add-ins and am unsure exactly what is involved and how to go about creating the installer.

Can anyone share any experience/tips/examples that would help me please?

Thanks in advance,

B

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this Microsoft article on VSTO add-ins deployment to be an absolute life-saver; I don't know about Wix, though. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb332052.aspx

Answer (score 1):

I've not done this in WiX but I have done it in InstallShield.  Below with my notes from that time:

http://blog.deploymentengineering.com/search?q=vsto

One problem you will have is that WiX doesn't have a bootstrapper so you will have to find a way to chain the .NET Framework and VSTO redist ( also possibly the Office 2003 PIAs; you didn't say which version of VSTO you are using ) with your installer unless you choose to take the route that merely gates the install if those aren't found.

I recall using a DTF custom action to publish a certificate but I can't recall if that was needed for Office 2003 or only for Office 2007.